# Send class type after "as!" as an argument

Tags: ios, swift, class, types

I need to "read" ViewController, which was sent as an argument to a function, as a VC of the specific class. So I need something like that (we get a class also from a function arguments):

```
let vc = vc_from_func_args as! type_from_func_args
```

I can pass a class to let's say `isMemberOfClass()` by doing that:

```
let klass: AnyClass = MyClass.self
vc.isMemberOfClass(klass)
```

But I can't do the same thing with "as" expression. It gives me an error:

```
klass is not a type
```

How can we pass class (type?) after "as" as a variable?

Comment: The `as!` cast is a compile-time thing, it doesn't really make sense to be trying to pass it a runtime expression. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hm... I have some classes (VCs) let say three of them. And now I have three functions that do exactly the same thing (set some properties for these VCs) and then `pop/push` them within navigation stack. I need to pass to `pop/push` function `as! VCClassName` to have all working. If it doesn't make sense to send anything after `as` I can inherit all these classes from some `ParentClass` and put it after `as` in code.

Comment: Yeah, either make them have a common superclass or make them all implement a protocol that contains the common methods.

Comment: Hi, check out my answer... I guess its the easiest way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comments, this is exactly what protocols are for. If you want a thing you can call `pop` on, then make that a requirement for your function. If it's easy to list all the things you need, then just put them in your protocol:

```
protocol Stackable {
    var parent: UIViewController {get set}
    var child: UIViewController {get set}
}

func push(vc: Stackable) {
    // do the work
}
```

If you really need this to be a `UIViewController` that also happens to be `Stackable`, that's fine, too:

```
func pop<VC: UIViewController where VC: Stackable>(vc: VC) {
    // do the work
}
```

Then just mark your view controllers as conforming to `Stackable`:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, Stackable {
    var parent: UIViewController
    var child: UIViewController
    ...
 }
```

If you find yourself doing a lot of `as!` or `AnyClass`, you're probably on the wrong track in Swift.

Comment: Thank for your answer and for the right track. I'll go into concept of protocols in depth.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that...

```
if let checkedClass: MyFirstClass = vc_from_func_args as? MyFirstClass {
    //It only hits here if it is MyFirstClass
}

if let checkedClass: MySecondClass = vc_from_func_args as? MySecondClass {
    //It only hits here if it is MySecondClass
}

if let checkedClass: MyThirdClass = vc_from_func_args as? MyThirdClass {
    //It only hits here if it is MyThirdClass
}
```

Also you are tying to instantiate a little bit wired :-)

Change this

```
let klass: AnyClass = MyClass.self
vc.isMemberOfClass(klass)
```

To something like this

```
vc.isMemberOfClass(MyClass)
```

You don't need to create an instance to check if another object is kind of a class :-) But just use my code from above... Its even better than this one

Comment: I've created an instance just to show how we can pass it as a var but not a raw name of the class. I know about using `if let`, but it is not the case here because it has no difference with using three separated functions. Using `if let` I will diplicate code for them three times as I do now with separate functions. I will try one common class as a parent, hope this will help =) Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the same issue a little while ago, and ended up writing a `downcast` global function, and a protocol called `Castable` that includes the `asType` function:

```
protocol Castable: class {
    func asType<T>(t: T.Type, defaultValue: T?, file: StaticString,
        function: StaticString, line: UWord) -> T?
}
```

Basically, you can take any class object and write `myObject.asType(newType)` and it performs the cast. If the cast fails, it logs the failure to the console, reporting the types you were casting to and from, and the file name, method name, and line number where the method was called. I use it for debugging.

At any rate, the way that the `asType` and `downcast` functions are written, you can pass the type that you are casting to as a named variable, which is what your original question wanted to do.

The complete code for `downcast`, the `Castable` protocol, and the `asType` function are available at [this link](http://letvargo.mooo.com/to-throw-or-not-to-throw-error-handling-in-swift/).